# How to get the rate of duration bucket in promethues after using subtraction

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to get the rate of request duration after subtracting 2 buckets. However, the below query returns error. How can I get the rate after using subraction? If its not possible then how can I represent this?

```
sum(rate(duration_bucker{le="5.0"}  - ignoring(le) duration_bucker{le="1.0"} [1m])) by (data)
```

Error:`"1:96: parse error: binary expression must contain only scalar and instant vector types"`

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the `rate()` function individually to the left and to the right operand of the `-` operation:

```
sum(
  rate(duration_bucker{le="5.0"}[1m]) - ignoring(le)
  rate(duration_bucker{le="1.0"}[1m])
) by (data)
```